# Docker container not starting giving "OCI runtime create failed"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have installed the [Docker version](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/) 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
When I try to start any container it gives the following error

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/2c910acea8a0cdd4ea6e2dd87616897b4e62b0913ba5014415bd6066eaf36868/

docker info :

> [root@MDMNext99001 /]# docker info
>   Containers: 1
>    Running: 0
>    Paused: 0
>    Stopped: 1
>   Images: 1
>   Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
>   Storage Driver: devicemapper
>    Pool Name: docker-8:2-137344840-pool
>    Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
>    Base Device Size: 10.74GB
>    Backing Filesystem: xfs
>    Udev Sync Supported: true
>    Data file: /dev/loop0
>    Metadata file: /dev/loop1
>    Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
>    Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
>    Data Space Used: 46.2MB
>    Data Space Total: 107.4GB
>    Data Space Available: 39.08GB
>    Metadata Space Used: 675.8kB
>    Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
>    Metadata Space Available: 2.147GB
>    Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
>    Deferred Removal Enabled: true
>    Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
>    Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
>    Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
>   Logging Driver: json-file
>   Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
>   Plugins:
>    Volume: local
>    Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
>    Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
>   Swarm: active
>    NodeID: h13ain31eiurodrbe3bzz9bz3
>   Runtimes: runc
>   Default Runtime: runc
>   Init Binary: docker-init
>   containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
>   runc version: N/A (expected: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f)
>   init version: 949e6fa
>   Security Options:
>    seccomp
>     Profile: default
>   Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
>   Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)
>
> WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly
>   discouraged for production use.   Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev`
>   to specify a custom block storage device.
>
> > WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled WARNING:
> >     bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled

I tried running different container but it gives the same error.
I am new to docker, any help or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your host  OS, version, release. Also include `docker info`.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error with a `entrypoint.sh` file,

i solved with this:

On Linux or macOS, run:

```
   chmod +x entrypoint.sh
    git add entrypoint.sh
    git commit
```

On Windows, run:

```
git add --chmod=+x -- entrypoint.sh
git commit
```

Answer (score 4):

RHEL 7.2 is no longer supported and Docker does not test their release against unsupported versions. You need to upgrade your OS, preferably to 7.4, to resolve this issue.

I've seen a few people with similar issues in the past few days that resolved this same error message by upgrading their OS. Some of the older packages no longer work with newer docker releases. One of those problems is an outdated libseccomp: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35906

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve the issue by downgrading the docker version to 17.09.1-ce.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after modifying `/etc/fstab` and remounting all. A restart (of the host machine) fixed the issue.

As always there's surely something you could do to fix it without restarting, but restarting's probably just as quick even if you already knew what it was.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Mac with docker compose up. Maybe it helps someone down the road.

Error was:

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused “exec: \“/bin/sh\“: stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory”: unknown

What worked for me is to perform a *docker disk image reset*. 
See [troubleshoot](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/)

Answer (score 0):

Restart the docker service in windows using the command - "Restart-Service docker" and in Linux (centos or RHEL7) "systemctl restart docker.service" as a root user . This may solve the problem.

Comment: I tried restarting it but still, it is giving the same error

Comment: restart fixed my issue/.