# During start of Docker I get this message: "getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "read init-p: connection reset by peer"

Tags: mongodb, docker, plesk

I have Docker installed under CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 and Plesk Onyx 17.8.11, and everything was fine. For a few hours I can't start mongoDB or Docker anymore. 
I get this error message

`{"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:297: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \\\"read init-p: connection reset by peer\\\"\": unknown"}`

[image]

What could it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker container not starting giving "OCI runtime create failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074282/docker-container-not-starting-giving-oci-runtime-create-failed)

Comment: What is your docker version..

Comment: Try downgrading the docker version to 17.09.1-ce if it is higher

Comment: My Docker version was 18.09.2-ce, now my version after downgrading is 18.09.0-ce - this is the last version yum  shows me. How can I downgrade to a nonlisted version?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it, I downgraded containerd.io to the version 1.2.0 and Docker is running.

Answer (score 0):

Docker-ce 18.09.2 + Linux Kernel 3.10.0 produces the same problem as you. If we want to use Docker-ce 18.09.2, Linux Kernel 4.x+ is required.